# R nested loop search and replace very slow

Tags: r, loops, nested

I have 2 largish  dataframes and I want to search through the larger one and then replace a value based on a test of two variables (an integer and a char) between the two.  As shown.

But it is taking a massive amount of time.  Is there a way in R to speed this up and to get a good display of actual progress!

```
for (i in 1:146385) {
   
   progress(i)

  for (j in 1:2078) {


if (AltOne[i,4] == Alt1codes[j,1] & AltOne[i,7] == Alt1codes[j,2]) {AltOne[i,8] <- Alt1codes [j,6]}

  } }
```

Comment: Read about merge, closing as duplicate, see linked post to see if it works for you. If it doesn't provide example data, and expected output.

Comment: As zx8754 said, part of your solution can be implemented as a merge or a join of your data frames. You may need to filter the output rows to keep what is of interest to you later. That solution will possibly have a larger memory footprint, but it will be much faster. If you need further help, please, provide a good reproducible example to let us help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: Thanks.  Im interested in your comment "...you may need to filter the output rows".  Can you elaborate?  As I get more rows in the output then the input!  Eg. df1  #146385 recs & df2 #2078.  Yet merge (have tried multiple types, inner outer etc) is #152796 recs?